# Data Structure search record

Tags: data-structures

The question asked by interview Panel..Web application user can select the favorite sports, one user has a number of Favourite sports.e.g User John has Favourites sport as Football, Soccer, Tennis. User Alen has favorites sport as BaseBall,BasketBall.

Consider Million of users, Which algorithm in Data structure uses to search users associated with Football or scoccer.

First I gave an answer as HashMap but interview panel told me it cause Memory issue, another way I can use Binary Search tree, but he is not satisfied with the answer.
Can anyone please explain to me what is a good way to get all users with favorite sport using DS algorithm.

Comment: HashMap means Football -{user1, user2.... } like mapping cause memory issue?

Comment: user as key and value as the list of sports user likes

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use HashMap by mapping user as key and list of sports as value as you mentioned. And its very common to come with this solution first at interview to see if it satisfies the interviewers.

A better solution can be building a graph of users and sports where there will be uni-directional edge from sport item node i.e. football to user nodes i.e. foo, bar. For any query for sport item i.e. football, we can traverse the graph considering `football` as source node. All the nodes which will be traversed are the list of users whose one of the favorite sports is football. This way, it will space efficient.

Considering the time complexity of traversing the graph for each query, where time complexity of graph traversal is `O(E)` where `E = all users` in worst case. So, we can cache some frequent query result using `HashMap`. Again, to cope with space, we can simulate LRU cache with `HashMap`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: you mean to say create a binary search tree each parent node(Games) linked with child node(userid) eg. Football is a parent node and its child node is the user who likes Football.